# How do I change Parse ACL settings back to Public Read/Write?

Tags: parse-platform, acl

I was experimenting with Parse's ACL settings in my app, but now I have a problem: All my objects are now created without the permission to write. I can change them back in the data browser, but I don't see how to reset the defaults back to Public Read and Public Write.  When I change the Data Browser settings, new objects are still created without write access.

I appreciate your help.  I saw this post:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33929358/cannot-edit-parse-user-while-they-are-offline-how-do-i-enable-acl-public-write

which seems to mention the same problem, but nobody answered it.

Eli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/protect-user-data-with-new-parse-features/), you can set the default ACL by:

```
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

Did you try this?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did try that before posting my question,, but it did not fix the problem.

Comment: I put the above line of code in my app delegate, just below the Parse initialization. No effect.  I've also tried deleting the app from the simulator, also with no effect.  My objects are always created in the Data Browser as "Public Read, (objectID)" instead of "Public Read and Write"  I've also tried clicking on the ACL settings, but they also don't help.  The settings change back with every new object.

Comment: Strange - maybe better to contact directly the Parse guys via support?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my problem had nothing to do with Parse itself or the data browser.  I was simply neglecting to unwrap some optionals.  Frustrating problem, easy solution.